# Syntax error from spread attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I am using yeoman generator [react-webpack](https://github.com/newtriks/generator-react-webpack). I am trying to use spread attributes in the Main.js component:

```
require('normalize.css');
require('styles/App.css');

import React from 'react';

var FixedDataTable = require('fixed-data-table');

const TextCell = ({rowIndex, data, col, ...props}) => (
  <Cell {...props}>
    {data.getObjectAt(rowIndex)[col]}
  </Cell>
);

let yeomanImage = require('../images/yeoman.png');

class AppComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="index">
        <img src={yeomanImage} alt="Yeoman Generator" />
        <div className="notice">Please edit <code>src/components/Main.js</code> to get started!</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

AppComponent.defaultProps = {
};

export default AppComponent;
```

I keep getting this error:

ERROR in ./src/components/Main.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/dev/react/reactwebpack/src/components/Main.js: Unexpected token (8:41)

```
let yeomanImage = require('../images/yeoman.png');
const ImageCell = ({rowIndex, data, col, ...props}) => (
<ExampleImage src={data.getObjectAt(rowIndex)[col]}/>);

at Parser.pp.raise (C:\dev\react\react-webpack\node_modules\babylon\index.js:1378:13)
```

What am I missing in the webpack or babel configs? (The config files are the same as the generator's).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's an ES7 feature. You need the `transform-object-rest-spread` preset for babel.

The generator you are using is itself using [this one](https://github.com/weblogixx/react-webpack-template).
It comes with a `.babelrc` and that is the place you need to enable the extra plugin:

```
"plugins": ["...other plugin", "transform-object-rest-spread"]
```

It also needs to be npm installed and probably added to your `package.json` file by doing a `npm install --save babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread`.

That plugin is included in babel's `stage2` preset too (`babel-preset-stage-2` is the full npm package name).

Comment: It works! Thanks so much! I actually had to run: npm install babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread, and add "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"] to .babelrc to get rid of the error.

Comment: Good to know, updated the answer with your extra fix details.

Comment: *"That's an ES7 feature."* No it's not! It's a proposal for a future ES version. ES7 is already finalized (feature-wise at least).

Comment: As a proposal I mean.